# How to track a file from NFS in Linux is being locked?

Tags: linux, nfs, redhat-enterprise-linux, lock

I've some codes on a NFS which is shared with two load balancer servers. Sometimes the waiting time of a request is getting longer and I suspect the files may be getting locked with a request while another request is trying to use the same file.

How can I debug or use any other tool to trace or find whether a file is getting locked ? And If locked, can I find how long its being locked and by which process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `fuser` or `lsof` to see if a file is in use on a system. `fuser` is the most sensible if you're curious about a particular file, while `lsof` is best for if you're curious about an entire directory.

The man pages for either describe their use well: http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof